# Ruby syntax when invoking a method

Tags: ruby

Found this source code on GitHub:

```
def objects_from_response(klass, request_method, path, options={})
  response = send(request_method.to_sym, path, options)[:body]
  objects_from_array(klass, response)
end
```

For this specific line:

```
response = send(request_method.to_sym, path, options)[:body]
```

What is that `[:body]` syntax after the method?

Comment: Btw, using [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send) instead of `send` is much better if you only want dynamic method calling, not visibility bypassing.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, your question applies equally to `response = my_method(path, options)[:body]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`send(request_method.to_sym, path, options)` returns an object support method `[]`, for example a `Hash`, then call `[:body]` on it.